# How to retrieve list of records for same ID with null and not null values

Tags: sql-server

I would like to retrieve records greater than '20150101' from SQL server for the same AccountNumber where there are different 'Effective dates' 
in ascending order and the 'LastChangedDate' field becomes null for the latest 'Effective Date' as illustrated below in 1st set of records
Note: I don't want the SQL query to retrieve 2nd, 3rd, 4th set of records and Retreive only 1st set of records

1st set of records

```
AccountNumber   EffectiveDate   LastChangedDate 
1234567         2019-07-31        2018-09-14
1234567         2019-08-18        2018-09-14
1234567         2019-09-18        NULL
```

2nd set of reocrds:

```
AccountNumber   EffectiveDate   LastChangedDate
8456566           2019-08-18     2018-09-14
8456566           2019-09-18     2018-09-14
```

3rd set of records:

```
AccountNumber   EffectiveDate   LastChangedDate
8456777           2019-08-18     NULL
8456777           2019-09-18     NULL
```

4th set of records:

```
AccountNumber   EffectiveDate   LastChangedDate
8456777           2019-08-18     NULL
8456777           2019-09-18     NULL
8456777           2019-08-18     2018-09-14
```

Below is the current query which retrieves only 2nd set and 3rd set of records but NOT the 1st set of records

```
select count(AccountNumber) 
from table where EffectiveDate > '20150101' and LastChangedDate is NULL or LastChangedDate is NOT NULL
group by AccountNumber
having AccountNumber > 1

select count(AccountNumber) 
from table where EffectiveDate > '20150101' and LastChangedDate is NULL or LastChangedDate is NOT NULL
group by AccountNumber
having AccountNumber > 1
```

The above query retrieves 2nd and 3rd set of records illustrated in the example but I want only the 1set of records to be retrieved

Comment: Is `20150101` and `2019-08-18` looks in the same format (do you missing `(-)`)?

Comment: Your example query is just a count. Perhaps you can specify the output you require as I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding the question.

Comment: My query retrieve records only with 'LastChangedDate' as null or not null but I need to list the records only for which the 'LastChangedDate' is having Date populated for initial few months and this data disappear for latest dates.

Comment: Yes Date format is not an issue but I'm looking for the records for which the 'LastChangedDate' is NULL for recent records but has value populated for previous records, please refer to 1st set of records example. I want to retrieve only records with 'LastChangedDate' is having values as Data for previous months and NULL vlaue for recent months.

Comment: Just to add more clarity, for a record if 'LastChangedDate' is having a value as NULL in between any month then I need to pull only those records, for e.g. from Jan to Dec, if the Dec MOnth field is null then pull that record, if the 'LastChangedDate' is NULL in between any months from Jan to Dec for any year then pull that record as well

Answer (score 0):

Just add parenthesis:

```
select count(AccountNumber) 
from table where (EffectiveDate > '20150101' and LastChangedDate is NULL) or LastChangedDate is NOT NULL
group by AccountNumber
having AccountNumber > 1
```